# Trying to run Spock Specification using Gradle... "Test Events were not received" (In IntelliJ Idea)

Tags: gradle, groovy, spock

I am trying to run a simple Spock specification with Groovy, in a Gradle project. But I am getting this message `Test events were not received`.

Here is my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
}

group 'com.Sample'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'groovy'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11'
    testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-core:1.1-groovy-2.4"
}
```

Here is my spock specification :

```
import spock.lang.Specification
class SampleSpec extends Specification {

    def "validate string concat"(){

        given:
        def string1 = "hello"
        def string2 = "world"

        when:
        def stringConcat = string1.concat(string2)

        then:
        stringConcat == "helloworld"
    }
}
```

Here is the message I get when I run the Spock Specification:

```
> Task :cleanTest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileJava UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileGroovy NO-SOURCE
> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :compileTestGroovy NO-SOURCE
> Task :processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :test NO-SOURCE
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
2 actionable tasks: 2 up-to-date
9:20:33 AM: Tasks execution finished ':cleanTest :test --tests "SampleSpec.validate string concat"'.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:
Now my Spock tests are running successfully but I am getting this message:**

```
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass (file:/C:/Users/dtara/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/2.4.9/3334e99a8baae12d6e014d444149e337ceb99a00/groovy-all-2.4.9.jar) to method java.lang.Object.finalize()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

**Anyone knows that this means? Should I worry about it? **

Comment: What is the file path to `SampleSpec`?

Comment: Make sure your test file is in a "Test Source Folder". You can change this in Project Settings -> Moduels

Comment: @tim_yates The file path is : C:\Users\dtara\IdeaProjects\SampleSpec\src\test\java\SampleSpec.groovy

Comment: You need to put it in `src/test/groovy`, and preferably in a package

Comment: Answered below for both questions

Answer (score 2):

Ok, first question:

The tests should live in `src/test/groovy` not `src/test/java` (and packages would be nice) ;-)

Second question:

You're using quite an old version of Groovy, but until Groovy 3.0 comes out, you'll see that warning when using Java 9+.  It's trying to use things in Java that Java is going to remove in a future release...

It's fine to run with what you have at the moment (apart from maybe pull in the latest groovy -- `2.5.8` at the time I'm writing this)